# I'm unsure of the setup for this probability question from the society of actuaries

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

[image]

The answer is 0.223584.

Here is my attempt:

Company A: 
$\mu = 10000\\
\sigma = 2000\\
\text{40% chance of at least one claim}$

Company B:
$\mu = 9000\\
\sigma = 2000\\
\text{30% chance of at least one claim}$

Then $P[A < B] = P[\frac{A - 10000}{2000} < \frac{B - 9000}{2000}] = P[A - B < 1000]$.

From here, I thought it would be finding the area of the region described by $A - B < 1000$, but I wasn't sure if that was correct. Also, I am not sure how to incorporate the fact that there is a 40% and 30% chance of companies A and B filing at least one claim.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ be the total claim amount for company B and $A$ the total claim amount for company A. To calculate $P(B>A)$, you condition on whether $A>0$ and $B>0$:
$$
\begin{align}
P(B>A)&=P(B>A|A=0,B=0)P(A=0,B=0)\\
&+P(B>A|A>0,B=0)P(A>0,B=0)\\
&+P(B>A|A=0,B>0)P(A=0,B>0)\\
&+P(B>A|A>0,B>0)P(A>0,B>0)\\
&= (1) + (2) + (3) + (4)
\end{align}
$$
Handle each of the terms (1), (2), (3), (4) separately. The first 2 terms are zero (why?). The third simplifies to 
$ 1 \times P(A=0)P(B>0)$.
The fourth term requires you to calculate $P(X>0)$, where $X$ is the distribution of $B-A$ conditional on both $B$ and $A$ being positive (so $X$ is normally distributed with mean = $\mu_B-\mu_A = -1000$ and variance = $\sigma^2_B + \sigma^2_A = 2000^2 + 2000^2$), and then multiply that probability by $P(A>0)P(B>0)$.

Comment: I may be doing (3) wrong, but I got that $P(B > 0) = P[(B - 9000)/2000 > (0 - 9000)/2000] = P(Z > -4.5) = \phi(4.5) = 1.000$. Since $P(A = 0) = .60$, that would make the sum greater than 0.223584. What did I do incorrectly?

Comment: Just do $P(B>0) = 1 -P(B=0)=1-0.7$, using the fact that there's a 70% chance that no claim is made. (If the total claim amount is positive, then a claim must have been made.)